# SimpleListFilter called twice and finally ?e=1

Tags: python, django, filter, django-admin, django-1.4

I have an admin page in django 1.4.3 [final]. We use CF cards in a lot of hardware, each card connects to a VPN. I have a function which determines whether the card is online or not depending on its last feedback written in database.

models.py:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    ...
    last_feedback = models.DateTimeField(_('Last feedback'), null=True, blank=True)

    ...
    def online_status(self):
            nowtime = calendar.timegm(timezone.now().utctimetuple())
            seen = calendar.timegm(self.last_feedback.utctimetuple())

            diff = nowtime-seen

            if (self.state == 1) and (diff < 300):
                    return '<div style="width:100%%; height:100%%; background-color:green; color:white;">online & production</div>'
            elif (diff < 300):
                    return '<div style="width:100%%; height:100%%; background-color:orange;">online</div>'
            else:
                    return "offline"
    online_status.allow_tags = True
```

admin.py:

```
class OnlineFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _("Online")
    parameter_name = "online"

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
            return (("yes", "Yes"),
                    ("no", "No"),
            )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
            out = self.filter(request, queryset)
            f = open("/tmp/list", "w")
            f.write(str(out))
            f.close()
            return out

    def filter(self, request, queryset):
            if not self.value():
                    return queryset
            else:
                    out = []
                    if self.value() == 'yes':
                            for i in queryset:
                                    try:
                                            if i.online_status() != "offline":
                                                    out.append(i)
                                    except:
                                            pass
                    elif self.value() == 'no':
                            for i in queryset:
                                    try:
                                            if i.online_status() == "offline":
                                                    out.append(i)
                                    except:
                                            pass
                    return out
class CardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter     = [ ... , OnlineFilter ]
```

and everytime I try to set the online filter, the file `/tmp/list` gets full with the right set of cards and then filled with the default list - as if the filter gets called twice. And the URL in my browser says `?e=1` instead of `?online=yes`. If the filter is not set, it is called only once - giving only one set of cards in the file.

BTW: the `OnlineFilter.filter` method is out of the `queryset` method just so that I know what goes out of my code, in final release I would have put it in only one method ...

is this a bug? or a feature? Am I doing something wrong? If so, what?

Comment: It seems that it always gets called twice, even if the filter is off ... the file always contains the list twice. If the filter is set there is the correct one and the full list. If the filter is not set, there are two full lists. Anyone? Why is this happening?

Comment: sidenote: why you mix representation and logic? and you get a massive overhead with `nowtime = calendar.timegm(timezone.now().utctimetuple())` called for each card. Can't you just filter with regular django means, i.e. smthng along the lines of `.filter(last_feedback__gt=...)`?

Comment: I like the `.filter(last_feedback__gt=...)` the most. To be honest I don't know why it didn't hit me in the first place. I use it in many more instances and this one didn't cross my mind.

Comment: mix representation and logic? How should I display the differential, then? ... I need to display how long ago did the card respond.

Comment: If you posted that as an answer, I'd give that the "accepted" flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if django calls the queryset function twice - I seem to remember noticing that once before.  Not sure why though.  Regarding why the filter is not working, django expects a `QuerySet` to be returned, not a list.  You might be able to construct a query to determine online status, but given the complexity I suspect it will prove to be beyond the powers to the django ORM and you'd need to revert to raw SQL.  The alternative would be to create a list of primary keys, the simply filter the queryset by those, so:

```
def filter(self, request, queryset):
    if not self.value():
        return queryset
    else:
        pks = []
        if self.value() == 'yes':
            for i in queryset:
                try:
                    if i.online_status() != "offline":
                        pks.append(i.pk)
                except:
                    pass
        elif self.value() == 'no':
              for i in queryset:
                  try:
                      if i.online_status() == "offline":
                          pks.append(i.pk)
                  except:
                      pass
        out = queryset.filter(pk__in=pks)
        return out
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the `.pk` is that something I should define? Or is it something already defined by Django? Is that a method or an attribute?

Comment: It's always defined on models, and is the primary key field. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut

Comment: Oh, I always used the `id` attribute, as I rarely override django's default primary key. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Although your way is good, I think I will rather go with the `.filter(last_feedback__gt=...)` way.

Comment: Overall that is a much better solution, but at least you have the answer as to why it was not working.